# Can not add custom field to Y-Axis Average aggregation for visualization

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

When I try to add Bar Chart visualization, I cannot select any custom field for my messages for Average aggregation (like: "my_custom_field"). Messages are logged and contain this field. How to do this?

[image]

Comment: Please share mappings and ELK versions.

Comment: ELK v6.1.0, I don't understand what are mappings, nor how to check them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why, but when I create visualization via **Visualizations tab/Add new/Vertical bar chart**, fields are not present.

But, I can make visualization by:

1. *[OPTIONAL, probably didn't help]* Go to **Management/Index Patterns** and click **Refresh** image button in right top corner. This will create mapping types for fields that are new since index creation (this was in my case). Such field can be recognized when before its name there is "**?**", means no type (e.g. **#** means field has type, like on the image below).
2. Go to **Discover** tab and select your field on the left, than click **Visualize** -> that will allow to select Average aggregate with your field.

This is very inconvenient, but works.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have a strong suspicion that your "messages" field is a string. Average aggregation works on numbers.
I checked this in my own setting and I couldn't run Average on "messages" with default settings, but I could run it on Unique Count.